# iOS - UIToolBar as inputAccessoryView for UITextView

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextview

I've added a `UIToolBar` with a `UIBarButtonItem` as inputAccessoryView for a `UITextView`. It works fine but the UIBarButtonItem is touchable outside it's frame, perhaps 50 pixels outside to the right. It's no big deal but it annoys me. Anyone know why?

This is my code (ARC):

```
UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, 320, 44)];
toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
toolBar.translucent = YES;

UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneWriting:)];
[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneButton, nil]];

self.messageTextView.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The toolbar seems to expand the active area of the buttons beyond their bounds if there are no other nearby buttons in the toolbar. Apple engineers must think it is better to try to guess where the user intended to press rather than not react at all.

Comment: If that is the case, for me it feels more like "sloppy" programming having the button react outside its' bounds, oh well.

Answer (score 7):

In iOS 6 it seems to behave as expected.
Nice tip: If you want the button to appear on the right instead of the left, use one of these:

```
UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
```

Then initialise the toolbar with:

```
[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpace, doneButton, nil]];
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope it helps you...

```
UIToolbar* keyboardDoneButtonView = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
[keyboardDoneButtonView sizeToFit];

UIBarButtonItem* PrevButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:105 target:nil  action:nil]; //<
UIBarButtonItem*  NextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:106  target:nil action:nil]; //>
UIBarButtonItem* doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(doneClicked:)];

UIBarButtonItem* flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *fake = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil] ;

[keyboardDoneButtonView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: PrevButton,fake, NextButton,fake,flexSpace,fake,doneButton,nil] animated:YES];
```

Use **Fake** Item to get exact pinch location on Button...

Comment: very interesting solution, this one worked for me, thanks.